# How to turn line graph into bar graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello I'm new to LaTeX and stackexchange in general. I currently have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[

xlabel={Trials},

ylabel=Moles ethanol burned,

legend pos=south east,

legend entries={Concrete},

]

\addplot table [x=trial,y=molburn] {procdata.txt};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
```

This is great, but how do I turn it into a bar graph?

If it helps, I'm using these packages:
I'm using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{siunitx}
```

Procdata.txt contents are:

```
trial   changemass  molburn qh2o    enthalpy
1   -0.44       0.0095  1590    -167 
2   -0.62       0.0135  816     -60
3   -0.61       0.0132  1590    -120  
4   -0.60       0.0130  1109    -85  
5   -0.62       0.0135  983     -73
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can mark code as code by putting it in the cursor and pressing the `{}` button when editing. And it is recommended to provide one single compilable code rather than fragments.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is very simple: add `ybar` to the options of your axis. The reason why I am posting an answer is, to a large extent, to give you some information on the preferred way of posting codes here.

1. Provide one compilable code instead of fragments.
2. Avoid loading packages that are not needed for the code.

After making these changes, the code for the answer is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% the following nice packages are not used in your code
% \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% \usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{array}
% \usepackage{colortbl}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{procdata.txt}
trial   changemass  molburn qh2o    enthalpy
1   -0.44       0.0095  1590    -167 
2   -0.62       0.0135  816     -60
3   -0.61       0.0132  1590    -120  
4   -0.60       0.0130  1109    -85  
5   -0.62       0.0135  983     -73
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar, % added
xlabel={Trials},
ylabel=Moles ethanol burned,
legend pos=south east]
\addplot [color=blue,fill=blue] table [x=trial,y=molburn] {procdata.txt};
\addlegendentry{Concrete}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And nowadays it is no longer necessary to write out "mole". ;-) With the brand new tikzlings package you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{procdata.txt}
trial   changemass  molburn qh2o    enthalpy
1   -0.44       0.0095  1590    -167 
2   -0.62       0.0135  816     -60
3   -0.61       0.0132  1590    -120  
4   -0.60       0.0130  1109    -85  
5   -0.62       0.0135  983     -73
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar, % added
xlabel={Trials},
ylabel=Moles ethanol burned,
legend pos=south east]
\addplot [color=blue,fill=blue] table [x=trial,y=molburn] {procdata.txt};
\addlegendentry{Concrete}
\end{axis}
\moles[shift={(current axis.west)},xshift=-1cm,yshift=-3cm]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the correct way to typeset "mole" :)